# Store numbers in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

How do you store a list of numbers in visual basic? I am working on a project and need to display a list of patients that match the max height. Below is my incomplete code. I find the max height, but how can I somehow store the indexes of heights that match the max height to display them? Thanks

```
Public Class Form4
Dim MaxHeight As Integer = 0
Dim x As Integer = 0
Dim y As Integer = 0
Dim MaxHeights() As Integer
Dim MaxHeightCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnFindMaxHeight_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFindMaxHeight.Click

    While x < PatientCount

        If Heights(x) > MaxHeight Then
            MaxHeight = Heights(x)
        End If

        x = x + 1

    End While

ReDim MaxHeights(x)
    x = 0

    While y < PatientCount

        If Heights(y) = MaxHeight Then
            MaxHeights(x) = y 'If the patient with the index "i" has the maxheight, add their index "i" to the array.
            x = x + 1
            MaxHeightCount = MaxHeightCount + 1
        End If

    End While

    x = 0
    While x < MaxHeightCount
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Names(MaxHeights(x)))
        x = x + 1
    End While




End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: PatientCount is an integer simply to count the amount of patients entered, it is incremented as each patient is added. I use it to know how many patients are in the arrays.

Comment: where is patient collection

Comment: the user enters patient data in textboxes in a different form. All I need now is a method to store the indexes that equal the max height to display them later

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
 Public Class Form4
    Dim MaxHeight As Integer = 0
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim y As Integer = 0
    Dim MaxHeights() As Integer

    Private Sub btnFindMaxHeight_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFindMaxHeight.Click

       for x=0 to Maxheights.count-1
          if(maxheghts(x)=maxheight)
    messagebox.show(x)
          end if
        next

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I need to be able to display the indexes as they are linked to patient heights allready, so I can't display them in a textbox

Comment: No I need to store the indexes so that I can display only those indexes in an array

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is get an array of the patients' indexes who are the tallest, you could try something like this:

```
Public Class Form4
Dim MaxHeight As Integer = 0
Dim MaxHeights() As Integer

Private Sub btnFindMaxHeight_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFindMaxHeight.Click

    Dim x as integer = 0;

    For i as integer = 0 to PatientCount - 1

        If Heights(i) > MaxHeight Then
            MaxHeight = Heights(i)
            x += 1
        End If

    Next

    ReDim MaxHeights(x)
    x = 0

    For i as Integer = 0 to PatientCount - 1

        If Heights(i) = MaxHeight Then
            MaxHeights(x) = i 'If the patient with the index "i" has the maxheight, add their index "i" to the array.
            x += 1
        End If

    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

This should store the indices of all the patients who have the `MaxHeight` in the `MaxHeights()` array. You could then easily access each patient's data by using a loop and the data in the `MaxHeights` like this (assuming you have a Listbox named `listbox1`):

```
listbox1.Items.Add("Tallest Patients")
For i as Integer = 0 to MaxHeights.Length - 1
    listbox1.Items.Add(Patients(MaxHeights(i)).Name)
Next
```

HTH. Let me know if anything's unclear.

Comment: thanks for the answer looks good, I'll try it out when I get back from school today :)

Comment: hey I've added my current code into the question. When I click the button to find max height the program freezes and I have to stop debugging. Any idea why?

Comment: You have an infinite loop running in this `while` loop : `While y < PatientCount...End While`. To fix it, add `y += 1` after the `If Heights(y) = MaxHeight Then` statement; ***AFTER*** the statement, not in it. Let me know how this works. (this is why I personally prefer `For...Next` loops since they increment the variables themselves :)) Also, just as a side note, you don't need the `MaxHeightCount` variable; you can just use `MaxHeights.Length`.

Comment: @Marcel, was my comment above able to help?

Comment: got it working, on another note, how do I clear an array to its original state? I have a reset button what code do I put there?

Comment: set the array equal to `nothing` or clear it, and then `redim` it before you use it again.

Comment: @Marcel, did either of these answers help?